# How can I point Visual Studio 2008 to a new path for projects?

Tags: visual-studio

I didn't see the option to point the workspace (or it's VS equivalent, I'm still learning the terminology for Visual Studio, but it is called a workspace in Eclipse) to My Documents/Programming instead of -- well -- wherever it is now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Craig said, plus if you do want to change the default it's in Tools -> Options -> Projects And Solutions.

I've never changed the default and never created a solution/project in the default location, which might tell you something about how relevant it is...

Answer (score 1):

Tools -> Options -> Projects & Solutions.

There is a Visual Studio Projects box.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the project you can specify whatever directory you want, you are not limited to the default.